# Can't Install Matplotlib-1.3.0 on Linux

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, installation

I've tried `pip install matplotlib-1.3.0`, `easy_install matplotlib-1.3.0`
and `python setup.py install`

but I always get the following error:

```
error: can't create or remove files in install directory
```

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/software/lsstlib/Import/enthoughtPython/epd-7.3-2-rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-26539.write-test'
```

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

```
/software/lsstlib/Import/enthoughtPython/epd-7.3-2-rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Since I don't have permission to write to the directory, or have a sudo password, how do I install matplotlib?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe you will have to [build from source](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/downloads) in your usr/local

Comment: It looks like you're trying to install `matplotlib` into Enthought Python Distribution. You should probably [read this page on using non-EPD installers with EPD](https://support.enthought.com/entries/22914233-Using-non-EPD-package-installers-such-as-pip).

Answer (score 0):

Add a --user option to you pip/easy_install/ python setup.py install. (PEP370).